# Magento Multistore - how to modfiy checkout.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I am using onestepcheckout.
I have added another webshop.

Now both webshops are using /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout/checkout.phtml

Problems:
We have modified in the past this file but I cant fix this problem:
->. We show the question: New at hatstore? Hatstore is our shopname. 
How can I make this question display dynamically? 
so "New at clothesstore" is displayed when they visit our other clothingstore.

->. We have forced also in this file a url to register:
hxxp://haststore.com/webshop/customer/account/create/
How can I change this, so this will be dynamically too:
hxxp://%shopurl%/%shopstorename%/customer/account/create/

I've searched a lot but couldnt find it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple if else condition in your template file
First get the store(webshop) ID / code from magento backend from Configuration > Manage Stores.

```
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if($code == 'hat') // suppose your store code for HATSHOP is hat.
{
  echo 'question: New at hatstore?';
  //anything else
}
else
{
  echo 'question: New at clothstore?';
  //anything else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow anz's answer. To get current store base URL

```
$this->getUrl('');
```

If need to get customer/account, then try like this

```
$this->getUrl('customer/account');
```